# nextLink1.replace("""), Making " act differently

Tags: java

`nextLink1.replace(""",())`, so basically I want to replace `"` with a blank. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `"` sign. Like this:

```
nextLink1.replace("\"","");
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will recognize the first two quote marks, but the third one will produce a syntax error.

Using an escape sequence will place a double quote as such:

```
nextLink1.replace("\"","");
```

You can find more escape sequences here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Answer (score 0):

`"` is Java's metacharacter used to start or end Strings literals. If you want to use it inside String literal you need to escape it first with `\` like `\"` (which is another Java's metacharacter used for example to create new lines mark `"\n"`).
Also *blank* String is not `()` but `""`. So try this way

```
nextLink1.replace("\"","");
```

BTW Strings are [immutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) which means this method will not affect original String, but create new one with replaced character. If you want `nextLink1` to contain String with replaced characters you will need to use

```
nextLink1 = nextLink1.replace("\"","");
```